# Tests not running after I click the run button in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

Junit tests in Intellij display the green run arrow next to the test method, but when I click the run arrow the test doesn't run. In fact nothing happens, no console output as I usually see when I click run.
Any ideas for what might be causing this?

Edit: The tests do run when i run mvn package though!

Comment: The weird thing is the name of the test is already in that box.

Comment: Is the test run if you create the Run configuration for it manually? Is the issue reproduced with the latest IntelliJ IDEA version (https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)? Can you please share the idea.log file (Help | Show Log in Finder). In case it contains private information, you may create the issue at the YouTrack (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue) and attach log to it privately.

Comment: You know just updating my Intellij fixed it for me. I think it was because my partners on the project made it in eclipse?